# How to get overridden content information of child class in the abstract parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

How to get information about child classes overridden methods information in the abstract parent class.
Example:

```
abstract Class A()
{
  protected void a1()
  {
    //some default content
  }
  protected void a2()
  {
    //some default content 
  }
}

 class B extends A
 {
    @Override
     public void a1()
      {
         //overridden content
      }
 } 
Class C extends A
{
   @Override
   public void a2()
   {
     //overriden content
   }
}
```

How get the information that Class c is overriding only  a2 and Class
 B is overriding a1

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean how to check if the method has been overridden?

Comment: Some extra concrete details would help understand the problem you're having.  In general, in a good design `A` should *always* assume that its subclasses have valid implementations of all of its methods.  That's the point of the contract!  If `a1` is only applicable to some of `A`'s subclasses, it's likely that the logic using `a1` should be pushed to the subclass that needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following to play around (through refelction):

```
java.lang.Class class = B.class; // or any other child class
Class dec = class.getMethod("YourMEthodNAme").getDeclaringClass();
System.out.println(" Declaring class: " + dec.toString());
```

// you can check the anme of returned class, if it's A for a given method, then method is not overridden, if it's child class name , it's overriden

**EDIT:**

You can also do this in a loop:

```
      Method[] m = class.getMethods();
      for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

         // returns te declaring class
         Class dec = m[i].getDeclaringClass();

         // displays all methods
         System.out.println("Method = " + m[i].toString());
         System.out.println(" Declaring class: " + dec.toString());
      }
```